# VBA macro for hiding rows based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am working on a sheet that has sections which hides/shows a number of rows based on a cell value (between 1-10).  At the moment, I have a handful of nested if statements.  This has made my workbook painfully slow.  Is there a way to shrink this code? Thanks.

```
If Range("B87").Value = 10 Then
        Rows("88:98").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
    If Range("B87").Value = 9 Then
        Rows("98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("88:97").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
    If Range("B87").Value = 8 Then
        Rows("97:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("88:96").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
    If Range("B87").Value = 7 Then
        Rows("96:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("88:95").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
    If Range("B87").Value = 6 Then
        Rows("95:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("88:94").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
    If Range("B87").Value = 5 Then
        Rows("94:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("88:93").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
    If Range("B87").Value = 4 Then
        Rows("93:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("88:92").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
    If Range("B87").Value = 3 Then
        Rows("92:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("88:91").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
    If Range("B87").Value = 2 Then
        Rows("91:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("88:90").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
    If Range("B87").Value = 1 Then
        Rows("90:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("88:89").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
    If Range("B87").Value = 0 Then
        Rows("88:98").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
```

Comment: Using Select Case is an option, or just adjust these to ElseIF and then you can lose all of the extra End IFs at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks. The code does work, so I will inquire at codereview section as well.  Just looking to speed up the workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a whole lot of basically the same code. I took a look and tried to make it more arithmetical, which shortens the code. See if this works:

```
Sub t()
Dim myVal   As String
Dim mainRow As Long, tweakRow As Long
Dim hideRange As Range, showRange As Range
Dim row1 As Long, row2 As Long

mainRow = 98
myVal = Range("B87").Value

If myVal = 10 Then
    Rows(mainRow - 10 & ":" & mainRow - 10 + myVal).EntireRow.Hidden = False
ElseIf myVal >= 1 And myVal <= 9 Then
    tweakRow = mainRow - 10
    row1 = (mainRow - (9 - myVal))
    row2 = (mainRow - (10 - myVal))
    Set hideRange = Rows(row1 & ":" & mainRow).EntireRow
    Set showRange = Rows(tweakRow & ":" & row2).EntireRow

    Debug.Print "For a value of " & myVal & ", we will hide range: " & hideRange.Address & ", and show range: " & showRange.Address

    hideRange.Hidden = True
    showRange.Hidden = False
ElseIf myVal = 0 Then
    Rows(mainRow - 10 & ":" & mainRow).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes - thank you!  This works well, and am now implementing across the workbook.

Comment: How would I go about calling this Sub as a Worksheet Change if I have multiple places where I would like this to apply?  Thanks.

Comment: @zanzibar why a worksheet change event? If you want to run this over multiple ranges, you could pass those into the sub first.

Comment: I admit my VBA knowledge is very slim, so my assumption was this had be placed in a Worksheet Change to dynamically adjust the sheet based on the values I input.  Any advice would be super helpful.

Comment: @zanzibar Yes, I was just checking if you knew that. Worksheet change event is ran each time a cell value in a sheet changes. If, instead, you just have other ranges to run this on, you don't necessarily need the change event...just add more ranges. I suggest looking up the worksheet change event, as well as how to pass variables to a subroutine in VBA. Play around and try some code out. When you have a question, start a new one here as it's starting to be a different issue than tour original one.  Good hunting!

Answer (score 1):

I might try a case statement.

Oh, or even use the ElseIf option which would reduce the amount of EndIf statements at the very least.

I think the case code looks something like this:

Select Range("B87").value

```
Case "1"

Case "2"

...
```

End Select

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `EntireRow` when using `Rows` or 'EntireColumn`when using`Columns`.

```
Rows("88:98").Hidden = True

If Range("B87").Value > 0 Then
    Rows(88).Resize(1 + Range("B87").Value).Hidden = False
End If
```